# Abnormally high MySQL writes and larger than normal Binary Log files. How can I determine what caused this?

Tags: mysql, innodb, replication, mysqlbinlog

We have a MySQL master database which replicates to a MySQL slave.  We were experiencing issues where MySQL was showing a high number of writes (but not an increased number of queries being ran) for a short period of time (a few hours).  We are trying to investigate the cause.

Normally our binary logs are 1 GB in file size but during the period that we were experiencing these issues, the log files jumped to 8.5 GB.

When I run `mysqlbinlog --short-form BINARYLOG.0000` on one of the 8.5 GB binary log it only returns 196 KB of queries and data.  When I run `mysqlbinlog --short-form` on a normal binary log (1 GB) it returns around 8,500 KB worth of queries and database activity.  That doesn't make sense because it has 7 GB more of data yet returns less than a 1 GB binary log file.

I see lots of these statements with very sequential timestamps, but I'm not sure if that's related to the problem because they're in both the normal period as well as when we experienced these issues.

```
SET TIMESTAMP=1391452372/*!*/;COMMIT/*!*/;
SET TIMESTAMP=1391452372/*!*/;BEGIN/*!*/;COMMIT/*!*/;
SET TIMESTAMP=1391452372/*!*/;BEGIN/*!*/;COMMIT/*!*/;
SET TIMESTAMP=1391452372/*!*/;BEGIN/*!*/;COMMIT/*!*/;
```

How can I determine what caused those binary logs to balloon in size which also caused high writes, so much so it took the server offline at points, almost like a DDoS attack would?

How could `mysqlbinlog` return so much less data, even though the binary log file itself had 7 GB more?  What can I do to identify the difference between a normal period where the binary logs are 1 GB to the period we had issues with the 8 GB binary log?  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Bill

Comment: If you get no luck here, this may be better on the DBA Q&A site. Note that someone may nominate it for moving it there.

Comment: halfer - Thanks for the recommendation.

Comment: I went ahead and created an account and posted it over there.  

http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/58401/abnormally-high-mysql-writes-and-larger-than-normal-binary-log-files-how-can-i

Comment: Thanks for posting that Bill. I'll vote to close here, so we don't get duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess that your log contains some form of `LOAD DATA [LOCAL] INFILE` commands and the data files associated with them. These commands do not generate much SQL output as their data is written to a temporary file by `mysqlbinlog` during processing. Can you check if the output contains any such `LOAD DATA` commands?

Comment: We haven't run any LOAD DATA since at least a week before this issue.  I searched the log files and did not find any instance of LOAD DATA.